# What is Groovy doing here?

Tags: inheritance, groovy, mixins, metaclass

I was trying to debug some code that uses mixins and I was able to reduce my problem down to this example. I have a parent class that receives methods via a mixin and a child class that inherits from the parent. If I try to replace a method on an instance of the child class it works *UNLESS* the method that I'm replacing was called on an instance of the parent class before it is replaced. If it has been called then I can't replace it

So this code:

```
class M {
    protected foo() { println 'foo' }
}

@Mixin(M) class A {
 def bar() { foo() }
}

class B extends A {}

def b = new B()
def a = new A()
a.bar() //<-- comment out this line and see the difference
b.metaClass.foo = {println 'winning'}
b.bar()
```

Will yield:

> foo
>
> foo

But if you comment out line 13 (the one with the comment that says to comment it out) you'll get:

> winning

Why does this happen? I expect there is some way this makes sense within the context of Groovy's metaclass model, but I don't get it.

This is Groovy 1.8.6

Comment: I can also reproduce this in Groovy 1.8.4. Smells like a bug to me; but I'm not too much into Groovy meta-programming, so I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for the note I'll be sure to include that if I end up filing a bug on it.

Comment: I'd ask this on the groovy user mailing list, smells like a bug to me...

Comment: Could this have to do with any method handler caching?

Answer (score 3):

The metaClass is looked upon on a method call and mixins have their own handler.
Both are lazily loaded, and static, if you do not call a method the static lazy loading does not happen.
Mixins take precedence over metaClass overrides which is why it displays foo and not winning if you initialize A.
A meta is defined on the object it is applied to, in order for it to be resolved per class you need Object.class.metaClass (i.e here B.metaClass).
Interestingly this yields :

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: B.foo() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: foo(), foo(java.lang.Object), bar(), any(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), find(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

Defining foo on B resolve the error :

```
class B extends A {
    def foo() { println 'not winning' }
}
```

Your answer is that the Mixin affects the class metastore, and class methods take precedence over object metastore methods.

Proof :

```
@Mixin(M)
class B extends A {

}

a.bar() //<-- comment out this line and see the difference
B.metaClass.foo = {println 'class winning'}
b.metaClass.foo = {println 'object winning'}
b.bar()
```

Yields :

```
foo
class winning
```

A different approach

```
class M {
    protected foo() { println 'foo' }
}

@Mixin(M) class A {
 def bar() { foo() }
}

class B extends A {
    def bar() { foo() }
}

class C extends B {
    def foo() { println 'wat' }
}

@Mixin(M)
class D extends C { }

def b = new B()
def a = new A()
def c = new C()
def d = new D()


a.bar() //<-- comment out this line and see the difference
b.metaClass.foo = {println 'winning'}
b.bar()

c.metaClass.foo = {println 'losing'}
c.bar()

d.metaClass.foo = {println 'draw'}
d.bar()
```

Yields

```
foo
winning
wat
wat
```

Comment: do you have a source you can cite for this info? I don't totally follow your answer and I cannot find any information on Groovy's metastore.

Comment: All this is taken from the documentation and fiddling with the console myself. Your question is very interesting and deserves a blog post in itself in my opinion. The Dynamic Groovy pages of the doc already provides some answers http://groovy.codehaus.org/Per-Instance+MetaClass